# Tabular Model: DISTINCTCOUNT on field with blanks in DAX

Tags: ssas-tabular

I understanding that DISTINCTCOUNT function in DAX is supposed to ignore blanks. From this I'd expect that if you had 2 unique values and a blank in a column the DISTINCTCOUNT on that column would return 2.

I am find this continues to return 3 i.e. the BLANK is treated as a value. How can I change this?

I cannot find anywhere in the tabular model where I can change the equivalent of NullProcessing. I have tried creating a column with just BLANK() and this returns a count of 1 too where I'd expect 0.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. To do this using the following DAX for numeric fields

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales'[SomeID]), 'Sales'[SomeID] <> 0)
```

OR

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales'[SomeID]), 'Sales'[SomeID] <> "")
```

for character fields.

Answer (score -2):

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales'[SomeID]), 'Sales'[SomeID] <> BLANK())
```